# Can't access named graph via a Dataset-bound QueryExecution

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena

this is how I create a dataset and add three named models to it:

```
Dataset dataset = DatasetFactory.create();
dataset.addNamedModel("NG1", model1);
dataset.addNamedModel("NG2", model2);
dataset.addNamedModel("NG3", model3);

Query q = QueryFactory.create(select_sparql);
QueryExecution qq = QueryExecutionFactory.create(q,dataset);
qq.execSelect();
```

Sparql query (#1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?p WHERE { GRAPH <NG1> { [] ?p [] . } }
```

This returns an empty ResultSet with no QuerySolutions. Why?

However, when I run the following Sparql query (#2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?g ?p WHERE { GRAPH ?g { [] ?p [] . } }
```

It works just fine, I get pairs like

```
<NG1> | foaf:name
<NG2> | example:example
```

as expected. The named graphs are checked and found here, but not in (#1) when I specify it with an IRI.

Comment: can you try with a property IRI please? I mean, "NG1" isn't an IRI for sure. Also which Jena version do you use?

Comment: @UninformedUser Jena 3.18.0-SNAPSHOT. Also, could you please clarify what you mean by trying out property IRIs? Shouldn't "NG1" be sufficient as an identifier within the Dataset?

Comment: try `http://foo.bar/g1` please. `<NG1>` is not a full IRI but resolves to the base IRI of the document. So I think this will be different in the query evaluation.

Comment: Yes, as @UninformedUser says - in the query, <NG1> will have been resolved to a full URI. Print the query to see this.

Comment: FYI: (2002-03) 3.18.0-SNAPSHOT is no longer under developement. The next version is 4.0.0.